# Deserialize N-ary Tree, pointer change issue in Python recursion function

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I am new to Python and encountered this Python pointer change issue when working on deserialize N-ary Tree question.

**Input:**
deserialize(String data), an example string is [1[2][3[6][7[11[14]]]][4[8[12]]][5[9[13]][10]]]

**Explanation of the string:**
1 is the root of the N-ary tree. 2,3,7,4,and 5 are 1's children. 6 is 3's child. 14 is 11's child and 11 is 7's child. And 7 is 3's another child.

**Question requirement:**
Write a deserialization function to convert the string to a Node

Node class:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, val=None, children=[]):
        self.val = val
        self.children = children
```

**Code**
My java code which passes all test cases:

```
    public Node deserialize(String data) {
        if(data == null || data.length() == 0) return null;
        return desedfs(data, 0, data.length());
    }

    private Node desedfs(String data, int st, int ed) {
        Node currRoot = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE, new ArrayList<>());
        for (int i = st+1 ; i < ed; ) {
            Character c = data.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                String s = "";
                while(Character.isDigit(data.charAt(i))) {
                    s += Character.toString(data.charAt(i));
                    i++;
                }
                currRoot = new Node(Integer.parseInt(s), new ArrayList<>());
            } else if(c == '[') {
                int rightindex = findpairpara(data,i);
                currRoot.children.add(desedfs(data, i, rightindex));
                i = rightindex;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        if(currRoot.val != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
           return currRoot;
        }
        return null;
    }

// Function to find the matching bracket. For example, in "[[12]]"
// If left index is 0, then return index is 5.If left index is 1, then return index is 4
    private int findpairpara(String s, int leftindex) {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = leftindex; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c == '[') {
                cnt++;
            } else if (c == ']') {
                cnt --;
            }
            if (cnt == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Now i would like to write in Python based on the same algorithm. This is my code which ran into pointer issues:

```
    def getmatch(self, data, idx):
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(idx, len(data)):
            if data[i] == "[":
                cnt += 1
            if data[i] == "]":
                cnt -= 1
            if cnt == 0:
                return i
        return -1

    def deserializef(self, data, st, end):
        currnum = 0
        p = st+1
        root = Node(-1, [])
        while p < end:
            while data[p].isdigit():
                currnum = currnum * 10 + int(data[p])
                p += 1
                root = Node(currnum, [])
            if data[p] == "[":
                matchingidx = self.getmatch(data, p)
                c = self.deserializef(data, p, matchingidx)
                root.children.append(c)
                p = matchingidx
            if data[p] == "]":
                p += 1
        return root
```

This Python function returns a Node with value as 1 and children list as **empty**. I printed the id of the root.children and looks like its pointer is messed up. Specifically, when we are adding Node 6 to its parent node 3, the id of 3's children list is different from the id of 3's children list when we are adding 7 to 3's children list. After we processed 6 and 7, the expected length of 3's children list is 2 but in fact it is 1.

Then I modified my deserializef function as follows:

```
 def deserializef(self, data, st, end):
        currnum = 0
        p = st+1
        children = []
        while p < end:
            while data[p].isdigit():
                currnum = currnum * 10 + int(data[p])
                p += 1
            if data[p] == "[":
                matchingidx = self.getmatch(data, p)
                c = self.deserializef(data, p, matchingidx)
                children.append(c)
                p = matchingidx
            if data[p] == "]":
                p += 1
        return Node(currnum, children)
```

This code passes. But I am not sure why this works and why the root.children keeps changing during recursion in my failed code. My uncertain guess is how Java handles pointer is different from Python and during python's recursion somehow it is creating new root during the process when we go from 3 to 6 and to 7.

Could i get some Python experts' opinions here? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected result is due to the last line in this block:

```py
        while p < end:
            while data[p].isdigit():
                currnum = currnum * 10 + int(data[p])
                p += 1
                root = Node(currnum, [])
```

You're recreating the array for `root` each time, so any previous children get lost. This isn't related to any Python/Java difference. If you look at your Java approach, you've created `root` when the nested `while` loop terminates. Here you've created `root` for each iteration of the loop.

There are several ways to fix it, but a minimal change fix should be:

```py
        while p < end:
            while data[p].isdigit():
                currnum = currnum * 10 + int(data[p])
                p += 1
                root = Node(currnum, root.children)
```

Note: Ideally you should create `root` at the end of the function, when all children have been processed. That is why your modified function works.